# How to upgrade phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to latest?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

How to upgrade phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to latest, without affecting the database, settings, and files?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This site will be useful for your purpose

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

> 1.)  Find Your Version
>
> Navigate to your phpMyAdmin interface and check what version you are
>   using. Notice if it mentions the “latest stable version.”
>
> There will also be a message as you scroll down the page if there is
>   an update to phpMyAdmin.
>
> 2.)  Find Your phpMyAdmin Directory
>
> Go to your current phpMyAdmin directory.
>
> If you are using XAMPP, on your local computer, typically you install
>   XAMPP to your main hard drive. So open your hard drive, then open the
>   XAMPP folder and you will see your phpMyAdmin directory.
>
> 3.)  Copy Your Configuration File
>
> Within the phpMyAdmin directory, find config.inc.php and make a copy
>   of it.  Place the copy someplace outside of your phpMyAdmin directory,
>   so you can bring it back here in a bit!
>
> 4.)  Download the Newest Version of phpMyAdmin
>
> Navigate to phpmyadmin.net, download the most recent version of
>   phpMyAdmin.  Extract the files.
>
> 5.)  Put the New Files in Place
>
> Go to your current phpMyAdmin directory, delete all the files in
>   there. Now, go to the new files that you just downloaded and extracted
>   in step 4. Copy all those files, into the phpMyAdmin directory. (The
>   directory where you just deleted everything.) All the new phpMyAdmin
>   files are now in place!
>
> 6.)  Add Your Config File
>
> Find your config.inc.php file that you made a copy of in step 3.
>
> Copy the file into the phpMyAdmin directory. (It stays in the top
>   level directory.)
>
> You are done!  Navigate to your phpMyAdmin interface and utilize the
>   most recent version of phpMyAdmin.

Remember to back up your database in case of potential problems.

Don't forget to restart the mysql/apache servers.

Comment: I have gone through the article earlier, which you have mentioned in your answer. Also, I have read all the comments given by the viewers. So, I am not confident in taking the trial, because I have done many setting/configurations for 4 years while I am using XAMPP

Comment: Trial leads to success.

Comment: Works great, but don't forget to stop/restart the mysql/apache servers or you get a load of warning messages etc.

Comment: Worth checking the PHP requirements of the new phpMyAdmin installation before you upgrade as you may need to update the PHP version in order to use the latest phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This procedure works well, I would just add that it also works for the very latest versions of PHPMyAdmin (not only the "stable" version).  in my case I went to GitHub to get a key bug fix I needed https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin .  adopting the procedure after downloading the zip from there went smoothly!

Comment: I did this a lot, in the past, to solve some problems related to buggy versions of phpMyAdmin 3.x which came with older versions of Xampp. But, presently, I had a bad experience when upgrading this application to a newer version: the original 4.6.5.2 that came with my Xampp 5.6.30 takes 4 minutes to import a 100 MB database, while the newer version 4.7.1 of this application takes 10 minutes to do the same job.

Comment: still valid in 2022

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure you change the directory path to the current version in the C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file.

**Example:** first line in file

(old version): **Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"** *to* 
(new version): **Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.1/"**.

I Was having a little trouble without this specification.

Comment: As well as line 3 <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.1/">

Answer (score 2):

Simple

Step-1: go to the PHPMyAdmin site

```
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
```

Then download the latest version

Step-2: Backup your old PHPMyAdmin folder and delete all files from this folder (C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin)
[image]
Step-3: Copy all files from the new zip and paste in to

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```

Copy *config.inc.php* from your old PHPMyAdmin folder and paste in to

```
 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```