# Getting 1064 error when importing sql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Hi I exported from MySql workbench to an sql file.
When I import it with Phpmyadmin I get this error.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a:4:{s:5:\"child\";a:1:{s:0:\"\";a:1:{s:3:\"rss\";a:1:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:\"data\";s:' at line 1

Comment: Use a real client phpmyadmin is a buggy POS.

Comment: I want to but I dont have access outside phpmyadmin cause thats using localhost and other hosts are blocked.

Comment: Update your phpmyadmin.
Here's a pretty solid guide: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131029/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-xampp-to-latest)