# Upgrading phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to latest produces an error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying update phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to the latest version using this guide:

[How to upgrade phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131029/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-xampp-to-latest)

however, as soon as I open the xampp-control and click on Admin in the MySQL section it produces an error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function PMA\libraries\PMA_langSet() in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Config.php on line 1021

I basically did what the guide except that I renamed my old phpMyAdmin folder (located in c:/xampp) to phpMyAdmin_old in order to have something to fall-back to in the event that something went wrong and then I copied the phpMyAdmin folder containing the new version into the same place where the old version - and it sure went wrong as you all can see and now I'm not able to revert back to my old setting even if I rename my old phpMyAdmin folder.

I did remember to save a copy of the config.inc.php as the guide specified and copy that one into the new folder.

I have tried to turn the server on and off several times to no avail.

I suspect, based on the \PMA_langSet(), that the error has something to do with the language settings - which I haven't tampered with.

How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refresh the browser's cache for ie users (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)

If you don't know how to refresh your browser's cache:

[How to refresh your browser's cache](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)