# A fatal JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, normalization, 3nf

I am trying to figure how to fix this error I keep receiving when I am applying Normalization to my tables in phpMyAdmin. This only pops up at the bottom of the screen when ever I try to complete the 3NF of the normalization process.

Below is a snippet of the error code I am seeing but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue. I have also tried several browsers and all seem to give the same problem.

Someone also posted a similar question about this error but their report code was completely different. I appreciate any help that can be offered! This is a link to what the error looks like from the phpMyAdmin UI

[image]

```
{
"pma_version": "4.6.5.2",
"browser_name": "CHROME",
"browser_version": "51.0.2704.79",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.0.10",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "disabled",
"php_version": "7.0.10",
"exception_type": "js",
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Unable to get property 'newTables' of undefined or null reference",
    "stack": [
        {
            "line": 235,
            "func": "",
            "context": [
                "                lastException = null;",
                "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                "            }",
                "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                "",
                "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                "    }",
                "",
                "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                "    return report;"
            ],
            "column": "",
            "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "new_func",
            "line": 249,
            "column": "21",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "n.event.dispatch",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "6410",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/lic//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "return M.access(a,b,c)},removeData:function(a,b){M.remove(a,b)},_data:funct//...",
                "void 0===c?d&&\"get\"in d&&null!==(e=d.get(a,b))?e:(e=n.find.attr(a,b),null==//...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "$event.dispatch",
            "line": 374,
            "column": "2",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "r.handle",
            "line": 3,
            "column": "3176",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/lic//...",
                "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                "return M.access(a,b,c)},removeData:function(a,b){M.remove(a,b)},_data:funct//...",
                "void 0===c?d&&\"get\"in d&&null!==(e=d.get(a,b))?e:(e=n.find.attr(a,b),null==//...",
                ";",
                "",
                "function sprintf() {",
                "/*"
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393",
    "incomplete": "false",
    "partial": "true",
    "uri": "normalization.php?goto=tbl_structure.php&back=tbl_structure.php"
},
"script_name": "normalization.php",
"microhistory": null
```

Comment: I tried ensuring I am using the right collation, and I also tried clearing my browsers cache and cookies. Still no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightly said by @IsaacBennetch, i too assume it was a bug in that package(4.6.x).

> Upgrading phpMyAdmin to 4.7.0 resolved similar issue faced.

**Upgrading phpMyAdmin:**

[How to upgrade phpMyAdmin in XAMPP to latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131029/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-xampp-to-latest)

> Copy new files to phpMyAdmin directory

Answer (score 0):

Since I experience a similar JavaScript error, I believe you have actually discovered a phpMyAdmin bug which I've reported at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12927

Comment: Thank you for you response, this left me really stuck so I've been doing the normalization manually since. I've also reported the bug as well. I'll be sure to keep tracking the any updates or feedback at github

Comment: was this bug sorted out ?

Comment: @tharif yes, and the fix was first a part of the phpMyAdmin 4.7.0 release.