# Error in phpMyAdmin when joining tables (TypeError: htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, htmlspecialchars

I have been trying to join two tables where the (on) condition column may contain null value.
I kept getting this following php error in php myadmin:

```
TypeError: htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, 
null given in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Results.php on line 2012
```

After a lot of investigtation, it turned out that the **phpMyAdmin version (5.1.1)** was not compatible with the **PHP version (8.0.13)**

Following this link to upgrade the phpMyAdmin to latest (5.2.0) the error did not appear again and I was able to run my query successfully.

[Updating phpmyadmin in xampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131134/4400699)

Also here is my query just FYI

```
SELECT * from table uc 
LEFT JOIN table u 
on u.id <=> uc.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigtation, it turned out that the **phpMyAdmin** version (5.1.1) was not compatible with the **PHP** version (8.0.13)

Following this link to upgrade the phpMyAdmin to latest (5.2.0) the error did not appear again and I was able to run my query successfully.

[Updating phpmyadmin in xampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131134/4400699)